# Sometimes the HTML5 canvas works and displays the image and sometimes it doesn't on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Sometimes the HTML5 canvas works and displays the image and sometimes it doesn't on IE9 for this webpage: https://www.barnwellmd.com/PainDiagram/PainDiagram.html. It always works in Firefox and Chrome.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the js code that loads the image:

```
function init () {
// Find the canvas element.
canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
if (!canvas) {
  alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
  return;
}

if (!canvas.getContext) {
  alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
  return;
}

// Get the 2D canvas context.
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
if (!context) {
  alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
  return;
}
var img=new Image();
img.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(img,0,0);
imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 700, 643);
pixels = imageData.data;
};
img.src="PainDiagram.png";
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you swap these two code blocks, Like how I have done below it should get fixed:

```
// Get the 2D canvas context.
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
if (!context) {
  alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
  return;
}


if (!canvas.getContext) {
  alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
  return;
}
```

Comment: Your code calls the function `getContext` and *then* checks if it exists... That's not "fixed", that's just pointless.